# WAtin :Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, watin

Am getting this error : **"Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.SHDocVw, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db7cfd3acb5ad44e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"**

I know many people already asked about it, but I've tried all the solutions suggested and  still nothing!
Am Using VS2010, .NET framework version 4, and am trying to use WATin along with Web browser control.

I've tried all the suggested solutions here
[WatiN System.IO.FileNotFoundException Interop.SHDocVw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433990/watin-system-io-filenotfoundexception-interop-shdocvw)

Comment: Please see this thread:
[watin error could not load assembly][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457635/watin-error-could-not-load-assembly

Comment: I have same problem, but no solution. Have you found any solution @demazid. If you found than please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit of a long shot.  Bring up your project properties and double check that your Target Framework (on the Application tab) is set to ".NET Framework 4", not ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile".

Comment: I have double check my framework is set  to ".NET Framework 4". Can you please give me another solution if you have.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Interop.SHDocVw in the project references.  Change Embed Interop Types to False and then set Copy Local to True.  Worked for me.