# What is the difference between MvcContrib.MVC3-ci and Mvc.Contrib NuGet Packages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, versioning, nuget-package

What is the difference between MvcContrib.MVC3-ci and Mvc.Contrib NuGet Packages?

I see they have different dependencies -ci has many more downloads. I'm assuming I want -ci for my MVC3 project, but how do I figure that out? What does the -ci mean?

Comment: I would have posted this question if you were late by 5 hrs.. Thx

Comment: =) I was surprised no one else had asked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From what I gather, `MVCContrib.MVC3-ci` is the latest version of the MVC3 package and `MvcContrib` is the old name for the MVC2 package.

If you visit the [codeplex site](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/releases) then you will see the release history for MVC2 (v 2.0.95.0 & v2.0.96.0) and then see a final release of this package for MVC3 (v3.0.51.0).  This MVC3 release was made on Jan 16 2011.

If you then goto the [nuget gallery](https://packages.nuget.org/packages/MvcContrib.Mvc3-ci/3.0.98.0) you will see in the release history that the releases started on Jan 15 2011 and continue until present day.

I would assume that they made a final release of the package on the codeplex site before moving it to the nuget site under the new name.

There is a link [here](http://groups.google.com/group/mvccontrib-discuss/browse_thread/thread/935bdb64995dcecb) which states that the `MvcContrib.WatiN` package was renamed to `MvcContrib.Mvc3.WatiN-ci` for this reason so I can only assume that it is the same for the `MvcContrib` package if it follows the same naming convention.

Note: This link also states that the `ci` in the name stands for continuous integration as the package is built using their continuous integration server.