# Watin-How to download pdf file atteched with IE popup

Tags: watin

I am trying to download PDF file using Watin but I can't download file. I have wrote following code but it doesn't work. [Actual scenario is atteched with image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiTOi.png). 
please click on link.

IE ie = IE.AttachToIE(Find.ByUrl("Url here..."));--Its give error.

```
FileDownloadHandler handler = new FileDownloadHandler(fullFileName);
using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher, handler))
{
    lnkDoc.Click();
    try
    {
        handler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(30);
        handler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(100);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This new window you try to attach to is showing a PDF. WatiN can't attach to these kind of windows.

Comment: What is the recommended way to test this then? :-)

Comment: Aha, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191897/how-to-check-if-pdf-was-successfully-opened-in-the-browser-using-watin